# How much time does time take?

Tags: bash, time, keyword

The shell keyword `time` can be used to time how long a process takes, but how much overhead does `time` itself actually add to the process?

In other words, how much slower does a command run when being timed with `time`:

```
time grep "a string"
```

...than when it isn't being timed:

```
grep "a string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

Sometimes [it's easy to confuse `time` utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70655/108618). You explicitly asked about "the shell keyword `time`".

---

#### Code

The following code will run measured `true` (which is a shell builtin in Bash) *n* times and then unmeasured `true` the same number of times. Subtract the respective results and divide by *n*.

```
export n=10000000
time bash -c 'for ((i=1;i<=n;i++)); do time true; done' 2>/dev/null
time bash -c 'for ((i=1;i<=n;i++)); do      true; done' 2>/dev/null
```

---

#### Example

For `n=10000000` I got respectively:

```
real    1m32.693s
user    1m13.679s
sys     0m18.998s
```

```
real    0m39.344s
user    0m39.343s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Respective differences:

```
real    53.349s
user    34.336s
sys     18.998s
```

Per one `time`:

```
real    5.3349μs
user    3.4336μs
sys     1.8998μs
```

---

#### Analysis

These depend on the general and temporary speed of the OS, so your results will vary. My testbed was a laptop with i7 CPU, Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Bash 4.4.20. I also have a lot slower computer as a home router/server. There the results were like `36μs`, `21μs`, `15μs`. Now you know what magnitude to expect.

I also tested with different values of *n*. Total times showed good linearity. In other words results "per one `time`" don't depend on *n*. Regarding my code, this was expected.

---

#### Conclusions

`time` in my Bash provides measurements with resolution of 1 ms. Even on a relatively slow computer the overhead is over 20 times smaller. I would say it's negligible.

---

#### Bonus

How about the other `time`?

On my laptop I replaced `time` in the loop with `/usr/bin/time` (and `true` with `/bin/true` in both lines because `/usr/bin/time true` cannot use the `true` builtin). These are (somewhat rounded) results per one `/usr/bin/time` obtained with `n=100000`:

```
real    600μs
user    530μs
sys      80μs
```

The external executable is about 100 times slower than the builtin. In reality a single invocation of `/usr/bin/time` may take much longer because the OS may need to read the executable file from HDD. Then the file gets cached so in my artificial test the rest of the loop benefits and this initial delay will become insignificant if *n* is large enough.

In comparison the `time` provided by Bash should be equally fast even for its first run because `bash` is already loaded (I haven't tested this though).

Back to `/usr/bin/time`. I expect the overhead to easily exceed 1 ms on slower machines.

Comment: This is a perfect answer except for a caveat - I wouldn't call a difference of 20 times as much negligible. On your computer maybe, but on a slower computer or in the case of severely limited resources it could be the difference between a second and 20 seconds.

Comment: I didn't know at all that there was a `/usr/bin/time`. What's the reason that this exists in addition to the default shell keyword?

Comment: @Hashim I think POSIX requires `time` to be a separate executable (compare [the `cd` case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819/108618), even if [a builtin is a must](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38809/108618)). In this context the external `time` is the obligatory base and the shell keyword is an optional addition. Some shells may not provide such keyword at all. The keyword in Bash allows us to measure compound commands, pipes, other builtins etc. You cannot do this with `/usr/bin/time`, unless you spawn an additional shell; but this shell introduces a delay, so you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test how much does `time` takes by wrapping it into another `time`:

```
time time true
```

Note: I'm adding `true` which is the simple command which 'do nothing'.

> true - do nothing, successfully - `man true`

On mine, it shows:

```
real:0m0.000s user:0m0.000s sys:0m0.000s
```

Even with 20 occurrences:

```
$ time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time time true true
real:0m0.000s user:0m0.000s sys:0m0.000s
```

Here are 1000:

```
$ eval $(for i in $(seq 1 1000); do printf "time "; done) true
real:0m0.000s user:0m0.000s sys:0m0.000s
```

---

`man time` gives some clues how the time is calculated:

> Most information shown by time is derived from the wait3(2) system call.  The numbers are only as good as those returned by wait3(2).  On systems that do not have a wait3(2) call that returns status information, the times(2) system call is used instead.  However, it provides much less information than wait3(2), so on those systems time reports the majority of the resources as zero.

For further technical details, check: `man 2 wait3` or `man wait4`.

---

To debug `time` on Linux, you can use `strace`, e.g.

```
$ strace -f time true
```

To count time of syscalls (`-c`) and summarise the time differences (`-s`), run:

```
$ strace -fwc time true
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 30.91    0.007723          69       112           write
 27.19    0.006794        6794         1           wait4
 20.44    0.005107         340        15        13 execve
  7.43    0.001855        1855         1           clone
  2.94    0.000734         122         6         6 access
...
```

Here is how to debug `time` 10 times:

```
$ strace -fwc $(echo $(for i in $(seq 1 10); do printf "time "; done)) true | head
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 87.35    1.057704      105770        10           wait4
  7.33    0.088807          79      1120           write
  2.25    0.027275         222       123       112 execve
  1.37    0.016571        1657        10           clone
  0.32    0.003913          71        55           mmap
  0.32    0.003844         116        33        33 access
  ...
```

And 1000 times:

```
$ strace -fwc $(echo $(for i in $(seq 1 100); do printf "time "; done)) true | head
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.66  112.115311     1121153       100           wait4
  0.77    0.874091          78     11200           write
  0.24    0.271382         226      1203      1102 execve
  0.16    0.179477        1795       100           clone
  0.03    0.037229         123       303       303 access
  0.03    0.036702          73       505           mmap
...
```

Obviously running under the debugger, the time is going to be slower when running the actual command, but it can give the general idea what kind of syscalls are in use and how much time they can use compared to others.

Comment: -1 because the answer is misleading (inadvertently, I believe), it confuses two `time`s. The question explicitly mentions "the shell keyword `time`". You cite `man time`, it applies to `/usr/bin/time` or so, a separate executable. The test with `strace` uses the executable. It's relatively slow because it creates many processes. Each `time` prints the result of its own measurement. When you test `time time … true` in Bash, you get *one* result. This suggests the parser is smart enough to compact many `time`s to one and the measuring code is executed *once*. 1000 `time`s only engage the parser.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski   *"When you test `time time … true` in Bash, you get one result."* -- Good point.  So what about `time \`time true\``, which produces:

real 0m0.000s, 
user 0m0.000s, 
sys 0m0.000s,  and

real 0m0.003s, 
user 0m0.001s, 
sys 0m0.002s.  Is the overhead of the extra shell involved?   Could we just subtract the output of  `time \`true\``: 
real 0m0.001s, 
user 0m0.001s, 
sys 0m0.000s (although the subshell seems to introduce variance)?

Comment: @sawdust Reasonable approach at first glance, but no cigar. I believe this should extend your idea: `eval $(for i in $(seq 1 100); do printf '$(time '; done) true $(for i in $(seq 1 100); do printf ')'; done)`. But `watch -n 0 pidof bash` reveals multiple processes are spawned. It's almost painfully clear with `1000` on my laptop. *Maybe* we can get some results by comparing the version with `printf '$(time '` to a version with `printf '$('`. We need one hardcoded `time` before `eval` in both cases then. Multiple runs and some statistical analysis may help.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, time does nothing more than wait (literally, it calls `wait3()` which completely stops the execution of `time`'s own process) for the child process to finish and then asks the kernel about the resource usage statistics of the child. So there is practically no impact of `time` on the run-time of the child process.

These statistics seem to always be collected. There seems to be no "start monitoring" mode or something that would slow down the child process. I use "seem" here, because I could not look into the code and could not find a source that explicitly confirmed that.

Source / Entrance to this rabbit hole: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html